# How to access values from this complex JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

I am working with [AbsoluteOrientationSensor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbsoluteOrientationSensor)

I have an object that contains the values of the accelerometer of the phone.

The values that I need are nested inside an Symbol in the Object.

How do I access those values?

The Object Name is "message".

I have already tried this

```
console.log(message.__sensor__.quaternion);
```

But I am getting the result as "undefined".

I have never worked with the *Symbol* data type in JavaScript before.

The Values that I want to access are the **quaternion values**

This is the screenshot of the Object Structure -

[image: The Object that I'm working with]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OrientationSensor#Properties):

> ### Properties
>
> `OrientationSensor.quaternion`: Returns a four element Array whose elements contain the components of the unit quaternion representing the device's orientation.

So:

```
console.log(message.quaternion);
```

You can also see in the screenshot that the object itself has a getter `quaternion`.

---

> I have never worked with the Symbol data type in JavaScript before.

Symbols are used for various reasons as property names, but if they are used, it almost always means that you, as a consumer of the API, are not supposed to access that value directly. Instead you should use the "public" API the object provides to access this data, such as in this case.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I'm getting four values which are all undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access the data before the sensor has a reading. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs#Readings

Answer (score 0):

```js
function GetSymbol(object, name) {
  const string = `Symbol(${name})`
  return Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(object).find(symbol => symbol.toString() === string)
}

const __sensor__ = GetSymbol(message, "__sensor__")

console.log(message[__sensor__])
```

Comment: @FelixKling i thought the question was about accessing Symbol property

Comment: Kind of, I guess `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` . On a higher level the question is about how to access the data there, and the answer is to use the public API to do so.